# Container settings in text output Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm trying to make a render a text output with an automatic scrollbar that is activated when the text becomes too wide or long. For the moment I achieved the scrollbar on the `x-axis` with container=pre as an argument in the Textoutput in the UI.

What I would want is that the output in the text output limits itself to 4 or 5 rows and then to have a scrollbar in order to see the remaining rows.

I looked at all the posts that I could find for the topic (that's why I implemented the container=pre) but I couldn't find a way to solve the y-axis scrollbar. I understand that it has something to do with overflow y: "auto" in the tags' settings but I can't make it work out, maybe I'm placing it wrong. 
Thank you. 
Here's an example:

```
# Shiny example
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(stringi)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Data 
  # Some random letters
names<- stringi::stri_rand_strings(100,20)
  # Some random numbers
numbers<- runif(100,0,100000)
  # a df 
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(names, numbers))

shinyApp(
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    absolutePanel(id="panel", fixed = FALSE,
                  draggable = F, top = 80, left = "auto", right = 60, bottom = "auto",
                  width = 290, height = 370,
                  box( title = "Box example",
                       status = "warning", width = 230, solidHeader = T,
                       pickerInput(
                         inputId = "select_nb_names", 
                         choices = names,
                         multiple = TRUE, 
                         selected = NULL, 
                         width = 190,inline = FALSE),
                       # the textoutput that only has an x-axis scrollbar
textOutput("TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll",container = pre ))))),


server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  output$TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll<- renderText(
    paste0( input$select_nb_names," : ",df$numbers[df$names%in%input$select_nb_names],"\n"))


}

# Run the application 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a scrolls using CSS. In shiny, use the `tags$style` tag to define the css properties and wrap in a `tags$head` tag. You can either target element using the ID of the output element (i.e.,`#TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll`), the shiny class for text outputs (i.e., `shiny-text-output`), or the tag name (i.e., `pre`). If you have more than one element that should receive the same treatment, then using `.shiny-text-output` is a better option.

To create a scroll for the desired element (as in the example; using ID), set the height and width properties first, and then use the `overflow: scroll`. For example:

```css
#TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll {
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

Adjust the height and width as needed. There are other scroll options available. See Mozilla's CSS guide on the overflow property. Here's the full example:

```r
# Shiny example 
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(stringi)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Data 
# Some random letters
names<- stringi::stri_rand_strings(100,20)
# Some random numbers
numbers<- runif(100,0,100000)
# a df 
df<- as.data.frame(cbind(names, numbers))

shinyApp(
    ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            tags$head(
                tags$style(
                    "#TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 60px;
                        overflow: scroll;
                    }"
                ),
            ),
            absolutePanel(id="panel", fixed = FALSE,
                          draggable = F, top = 80, left = "auto", right = 60, bottom = "auto",
                          width = 290, height = 370,
                          box( title = "Box example",
                               status = "warning", width = 230, solidHeader = T,
                               pickerInput(
                                   inputId = "select_nb_names", 
                                   choices = names,
                                   multiple = TRUE, 
                                   selected = NULL, 
                                   width = 190,inline = FALSE),
                               # the textoutput that only has an x-axis scrollbar
                               textOutput("TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll",container = pre))))),


    server <-  function(input, output, session) {
        output$TextThatIWantToHaveAScroll<- renderText(
            paste0( input$select_nb_names," : ",df$numbers[df$names%in%input$select_nb_names],"\n"))


    }

    # Run the application 
)
```

Comment: Great thank you, I implemented it with .shiny-text-output and overflow-y: auto and worked perfectly. (overflow:scroll, like you said, also worked but with auto I don't have the scroll bar if it's not necessary). 
May  I ask why it's not necessary to wrap the content in tags$style with HTML(). . 
Thank you, have a nice day .

Comment: Glad it worked out! Shiny tags (`tags$x`) will render to html on their own. The `HTML` function will render strings as html objects. This is useful for elements that aren’t native shiny tags (e.g., svg elements). You can also use the `tag()` function to create html elements, but in certain situations (like SVG) it may be faster to write html markup as normal and render it with the HTML function.